# Can I hide a user from the Windows 7 login screen without disabling network access?

Tags: windows-7, networking, user-accounts

I have two user accounts on my computer.  I have a third "device-account" that allows network access to shares for non-computer devices.  I can hide this account from the welcome screen using the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\
CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
```

setting, but this appears to disable network access (the device thinks it's using an invalid username/password when this is set, but as soon as I deleted the key it started working again).

Can I hide this account somehow without disabling network access?

Comment: Try the methods shown [here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3432970/how-hide-user-accounts-from-log-on-screen-in-windows-7/).

Comment: The first method is the one I mentioned in my post, the other disables the Welcome screen altogether.  Sadly, I don't think this is doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Local Security Policy to not show last log-on name.

Local Security Settings->Local Policies->Security Options->Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name.

Obviously the cost is that you will have to enter a username, as well as password every time you log on.  Another minor annoyance would be the loss of the user picture used at logon...because there is no user listed.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the only alternative.  I was hoping there was some mystery solution that I hadn't found or already knew, but alas, it appears not.